# How to stop the overflow on to the appbar?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout

I'm trying to implement the `CoordinatorLayout`. But when i try to apply the below code to define an XML file it is also overlapping the appbar. What should i do to stop the overlap on appbar?

Here is an XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main.appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/main.imageview.placeholder"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/quila2"
                android:tint="#11000000"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.9" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/main.framelayout.title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                android:background="#00838F"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.3">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/main.linearlayout.title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:gravity="bottom|center"
                        android:text="Subbu kummithi"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="30sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                        android:text="@string/role_name"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:behavior_overlapTop="30dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:contentPadding="16dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
                android:text="This is for new activity This is for new activity This is for new activity"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/main.toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#00838F"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/main.framelayout.title"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
        app:title="">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Space
                android:layout_width="@dimen/image_final_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/image_final_width" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/main.textview.title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="Welcome Mr. Subbu"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/image_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/image_width"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/quila"
        app:border_color="@android:color/white"
        app:border_width="2dp"
        app:finalHeight="@dimen/image_final_width"
        app:finalYPosition="2dp"
        app:layout_behavior="com.realmilk.activities.AvatarImageBehavior"
        app:startHeight="2dp"
        app:startToolbarPosition="2dp"
        app:startXPosition="2dp" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And Here is the output when i run the above code:

[image: Overlapping onto the appbar]

Any ideas?

Comment: What about adding `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in the `AppBarLayout` and no `CoordinatorLayout`? This should fix the issue..

Comment: Actually... Why do you have a `Toolbar` element **outside** the `AppBarLayout` and under a `NestedScrollView`?

Comment: I can't understand.. would you mean i have to put inside the AppBarLayout or NestedScrollView. Where should i have to place?

Answer (score 0):

try add attribute `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in your `CoordinatorLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded">
.....
```

Comment: after adding android:fitsSystemWindows="true" half bar is coming meaning that remaining is overlapping again.

Comment: @KiranRaju I think it also needs added to the `AppBarLayout`

Comment: i added but no use still it behaving as before.

Answer (score 0):

Set `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in CoordinatorLayout, AppBarLayout and CollapsingToolbarLayout to reserve space at top.

If you want the background image starting behind the transparent status bar set `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in the main.imageview.placeholder too.

Comment: I added in ImageView but the result is same as before.. nothing is changing it is overlaping again half of the transparent bar.

Comment: As the Toolbar is out of the CollapsingToolbarLayout and anchored to main.framelayout.title it has not top inset protection.  A way could be adding a top margin to the Toolbar and adjust the maths in the avatar's behavior.